# Conservative extension in higher order logic?

Tags: logic, higher-order-logic

Specifically I am interested in the prerequisites of a valid extension by definition, like in FOL before introducing an n-ary function symbol (e.g. $f$) for the extension to be conservative we have to prove $\forall \vec x:\exists !y:\phi(y,\vec x)$. What theorems one has to prove in HOL for an extension to be conservative?

I would somehow expect it to be a general requirement, as in FOL a new relation symbol needs no proof to be safely introducible, but in HOL relations and operations are on more equal footing.

Comment: Uniqueness is not necessary for conservative extension in first-order logic. E.g., it is a conservative extension of the first-order theory of the reals to add a one-place function symbol $r(x)$ with defining property $\forall x\cdot (x \ge 0 \Rightarrow r(x)^2 = x)$. I.e., I've added a function $r$ that gives a non-necessarily non-negative square root of any non-negative real. This is conservative, but there are uncountably many distrinct choices for $r$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof systems for higher-order logic are not different in any important way from the proof systems for first-order logic. So, as long as your notion of "conservative extension" is phrased (as usual) in terms of provability, there is no difference in how to make a conservative extension.

Start with the syntactic definition of a conservative extension by a function symbol:

> **Definition.** A theory $S$ is a conservative extension of a theory $T$ if $T$ is a subset of $S$ and every sentence in the language of $T$ that is provable in $S$ is already provable in $T$.

Then we have:

> **Theorem.** Let $T$ be a higher-order theory with full semantics. If $T \vdash (\forall x)(\exists y) \psi(x,y)$, and $S$ is $T$ plus an extra function symbol $f$ and an extra axiom $(\forall x)\psi(x, f(x))$ then $S$ is a conservative extension of $T$.

*Proof.* Let $T_1$ and $S_1$ be the same syntactic theories as $S$ and $T$, but with first-order semantics (that is, Henkin semantics). Then we have $T \vdash \phi$ if and only if $T_1 \vdash \phi$ for all $\phi$ in the language of $T$, and a similar equivalence for sentences in the language of $S$. This is because the proof system does not depend on and does not care about the semantics that we choose.

Now, standard results about first-order theories show that if $\phi$ is a sentence in the language of $T_1$ and $S_1 \vdash \phi$ then $T_1 \vdash \phi$. But, because of the the facts in the previous paragraph, and because the language of $T$ is the same as the language of $T_1$, it follows immediately that $S$ is a conservative extension of $T$.  $\quad \blacksquare$

We could also look at a different kind of "conservative extension":

> **Definition.** A theory $S$ is a semantically conservative extension of a theory $T$ if $T$ is a subset if $S$ and every model of $T$ can be expanded to a model of $S$.

Then we have the same kind of theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $T$ be a higher-order theory with full semantics. If $T \vdash (\forall x)(\exists y) \psi(x,y)$, and $S$ is $T$ plus an extra function symbol $f$ and an extra axiom $(\forall x)\psi(x, f(x))$ then $S$ is a semantically conservative extension of $T$.

*Proof.* Let $M$ be a model of $T$. By the axiom of choice, there is a function $F$ such that
$$(\forall x \in |M|)(\exists y \in |M|) \phi(x, F(x)).$$ 
Because $M$ is a model under full semantics, $F$ is already an element of one of the sorts of $M$. Therefore, if we simply interpret the new symbol $F$ as $f$, this gives an expansion $M'$ of $M$ that satisfies $S$. It is immediate that $M'$ still satisfies $T$, because we have not changed any of the sorts nor the interpretation of any symbol in the language of $T$. The fact that $M$ satisfies $(\forall x)\psi(x,f(x))$ follows directly from the choice of $F$. $\quad \blacksquare$

Notice that in the second (semantic) situation, if we are looking at $(n+1)$-st order logic, the proof needs $f$ to be of type $n+1$ or lower. In the first (syntactic) situation, $f$ could also be of type $n+2$.

Comment: What do you mean by "no difference in how to make a conservative extension"? This question is much more slippery than you make out.

Comment: @Rob Arthan: in my mind, a conservative extension of a theory $T$ is a theory $S$ which extends $T$ and proves the same sentences in the language of $T$. Because there in no difference with respect to *provability* between first-order and higher-order logic, what difference would there be with conservativity? If you're thinking of some other definition of a conservative extension - or, more importantly, if the OP is - then it should be indicated.

Comment: The OP is asking about (an incorrectly stated) necessary and suffiicient condition for an extension to be conservative. When correctly stated (with the uniqueness condition dropped), the proof of necessity of that condition does not transfer to higher-order logic (because the proof uses completeness). So "there is no difference in how to make a conservative extension" is a useless statement. (Unless you just mean it is done by writing down a new axiom and praying.)

Comment: If $T$ does not prove $(\forall x)(\exists y)\psi(x,y)$, that sentence is still provable in $S = T+ (\forall x)\psi(x,f(x))$, so $S$ would not be a conservative extension of $T$. So it seems that the necessity of $T$ proving that sentence (which is the only assumption for $S$ to be a conservative extension of $T$) is still necessary. I have tried expanding my answer to clarify how I read the question.

Comment: so, drop the uniqueness and good to go? my confusion arose as a result of the book A Concise  Introduction for Mathematical Logic (2010) where on page 86 the following is stated: "Definition II. An explicit definition of an n-ary operation symbol $f$ not occurring in $L$ is a formula of the form
$η_f : y=f\vec x \leftrightarrow δ(\vec x,y)$ ($δ ∈ L$ and $y,x_1,...,x_n$ distinct).
$η_f$ is called legitimate in $T⊆L$ if $T\vDash \forall \vec x∃!yδ$, and $T_f:=T+η_f^g$ is then called a definitorial extension by $ f$, more precisely by $η_f$."

Comment: The more common application is when the theory has a definable function for which we want to create a symbol. It just happens that the same procedure works, in terms of provability, if we add a function symbol when the theory proves there is a total relation.

Comment: @CarlMummert: you aren't answering the (difficult) part of the question "what theorems do I have to prove for an extension to be conservative"? I.e., (in my reading) what conditions are necessary for an extension to be conservative?

Comment: If $T$ proves $(\forall x)(\exists y) \psi(x,y)$ then the extension $S$ is conservative over $T$ (by the first theorem in my answer). If $T$ doesn't prove that sentence, then $S$ is not conservative over $T$ (trivially, the sentence is an immediate consequence of the new axiom of $S$).  I think we're just talking about extensions of the form $S$ here, so the prerequisite is just the same as in FOL.  Perhaps you could state the precise question you are thinking about?   @Rob Arthan

Comment: I can't understand, can someone please further explain this to me please?